# How to extract value from Excel function?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I would like to extract a value from an Excel function. I have a database of over 3000 entries, where each entry is given as a DATE function plus some value. Here is an example: "= DATE(2014; 7;1) + 0,0180555555555556".

Is there a neat way to extract the second value over all the entries?

Comment: You can use formulas for this. Look into [`FIND`](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/FIND-FINDB-functions-C7912941-AF2A-4BDF-A553-D0D89B0A0628), and [`LEFT`](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/LEFT-LEFTB-functions-9203D2D2-7960-479B-84C6-1EA52B99640C)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use a US Locale, so in **A1** I enter:

```
=DATE(2014,7,1)+0.0180555555555556
```

and in another cell:

```
=MID(FORMULATEXT(A1),FIND("+",FORMULATEXT(A1))+1,99)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you want to **extract** or **subtract** the fractional part (you've used both terms in your question, and they are not the same.

Excel stores dates/times as days and fractions of a day. So:

To extract (return only the fractional part):

```
=MOD(DATE(2014; 7;1) + 0,0180555555555556;1)
```

To subtract (return only the integer part):

```
=INT(DATE(2014; 7;1) + 0,0180555555555556)
```

Or, you can just apply those functions to the cell containing the formula

In other words, if the formula is in A1:

```
=MOD(A1;1)  will return (extract) the decimal value
=INT(A1)    will return (subtract the decimal value) the integer value
```